# NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification) willChangeValueForKey: random crash on Release build

Tags: ios, key-value-observing

Recently I encountered some random crashes in iPhone, OS 9.2. The strange part is that I can't reproduce my crash on debug build, it only happens with release build. And it's not consistently reproducible. I did the same operation (open my app by opening a URL) several times, about one in ten times, app crashes.

Crash thread doesn't contain code related with my application. And I searched my application, I've removed all the KVO observer when they are deallocated, so I can't reproduce it on debug build.

Does anyone meet the similar problem? Is it an iOS issue or defect in my code?

Crash log is as below:

```
Date/Time: 2016-03-01 15:24:21.21 +0800

Launch Time: 2016-03-01 14:20:05.05 +0800

OS Version: iOS 9.2.1 (13D15)

Report Version: 105

Exception Type: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)

Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000200015a03c700

Triggered by Thread: 0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Global Trace Buffer (reverse chronological seconds):

3.636040 CFNetwork  0x0000000184c182e4 NSURLSessionTask finished with error - code: -999
10.973538 CFNetwork     0x0000000184c182e4 NSURLSessionTask finished with error - code: -1002
11.010070 CFNetwork     0x0000000184c182e4 NSURLSessionTask finished with error - code: -1002
14.318051 CFNetwork     0x0000000184c182e4 NSURLSessionTask finished with error - code: -999
20.328646 CFNetwork     0x0000000184c182e4 NSURLSessionTask finished with error - code: -1002
20.349845 CFNetwork     0x0000000184c182e4 NSURLSessionTask finished with error - code: -1002
22.382139 CFNetwork     0x0000000184c47104 TCP Conn 0x14f6399e0 complete. Fd: 22, err: 0
22.382727 CFNetwork     0x0000000184c48630 TCP Conn 0x14f6399e0 event 1. Err: 0


Thread 0 name: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Thread 0 Crashed:

0 libobjc.A.dylib   0x0000000183c4dbdc objc_msgSend + 28

1 Foundation    0x0000000184ea28e4 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification) willChangeValueForKey: ] + 324

2 QuartzCore    0x0000000186cbf374 CA::Layer::set_delegate(objc_object*) + 72

3 UIKit     0x00000001892c2538 -[UIView _createLayerWithFrame: ] + 580

4 UIKit     0x00000001892c1ff8 UIViewCommonInitWithFrame + 688

5 UIKit     0x00000001892c1ce8 -[UIView initWithFrame: ] + 140

6 UIKit     0x000000018931be60 -[UIActivityIndicatorView initWithActivityIndicatorStyle: ] + 116

7 UIKit     0x000000018931bbd0 -[UIStatusBarActivityItemView updateContentsAndWidth] + 148

8 UIKit     0x000000018931ba80 -[UIStatusBarItemView initWithItem: data: actions: style: ] + 432 

9 UIKit     0x000000018931b80c +[UIStatusBarItemView createViewForItem: withData: actions: foregroundStyle: ] + 144

10 UIKit    0x000000018931b604 -[UIStatusBarLayoutManager _createViewForItem: withData: actions: ] + 172

11 UIKit    0x00000001892b4330 -[UIStatusBarLayoutManager _prepareEnabledItemType: withEnabledItems: withData: actions: itemAppearing: itemDisappearing: ] + 332

12 UIKit    0x00000001892b416c -[UIStatusBarLayoutManager prepareEnabledItems: withData: actions: ] + 112

13 UIKit    0x00000001892b3f98 -[UIStatusBarForegroundView _setStatusBarData: actions: animated: ] + 836

14 UIKit    0x00000001892b3a18 -[UIStatusBarForegroundView setStatusBarData: actions: animated: ] + 688

15 UIKit    0x00000001892b2af4 -[UIStatusBar statusBarServer: didReceiveStatusBarData: withActions: ] + 188

16 UIKit    0x00000001892b29f0 _UIStatusBarReceivedStatusBarDataAndActions + 76

17 UIKit    0x00000001892b295c _XReceivedStatusBarDataAndActions + 96

18 AppSupport   0x00000001859d0270 migHelperRecievePortCallout + 212

19 CoreFoundation   0x0000000184585634 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 56

20 CoreFoundation   0x0000000184584d6c __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 436

21 CoreFoundation   0x0000000184582ac4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1800

22 CoreFoundation   0x00000001844b1680 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384

23 GraphicsServices     0x00000001859c0088 GSEventRunModal + 180

24 UIKit    0x0000000189328d90 UIApplicationMain + 204

25 MYAPP    0x000000010000f454 main (main.m:13)

26 libdyld.dylib    0x00000001840528b8 start + 4
```

Comment: Can you add your source code?

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I am seeing a very similar crash.

Comment: Also seeing this on 9.3.2 currently. Only seen on S phones so far, weirdly. It wouldn't be the first unretained-delegate bug in iOS...